# Fragment stacking RAM issues

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've an app where user can tap on many links that lead to another fragments. For example, you click on movie, it shows details about movie then user can click on actor, that actor opens another fragment with all his movies and you can of course click on the movie and this can repeat forever.

The problem is with the ram usage, is there a way where fragmentmanager manages the RAM? Some library or idea that I can use to solve this problem?

Comment: i encounter with that problem . you most to replace fragments not add .

Comment: But i want user to able to go back trough all fragments they opened.

Comment: you most to understand replace and add in fragment manager . if you replace  a fragment there is a empty frame in back stack and when you click on back button that empty frame will recreate